# C - Trouble inputting doubles to array

Tags: c, input, scanf

I know C++ fairly well and was told to translate a program I had written in C++ to C for use in a different setting. I have never written code in plain C before and I am running into some trouble. The following function is supposed to read a .txt file and input the values within to a double array, however whenever I print the array, all values are: `-92559631349317831000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00000`. However if I manually change a value in the code before printing I get the correct value. Here is the input function:

```
void FileRead(double *AttPos)
{
    int j = 0;
    FILE *in_file;
    in_file = fopen("DragonData.txt", "r");

    if (in_file == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        for(j; j<8; j++)
        {
            fscanf(in_file, "%lf", &AttPos[i]);
        }
        fclose(in_file);
    }
}
```

And here is the input file:

```
12345
0.13717085
0.91813290
0.73543816
-0.67362091
111
-63
11000
```

Comment: `&AttPos[i]` should be `&AttPos[j]`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Wow, that was my whole problem. I've been trying to figures this out for about two hours. Thanks a lot. I need more coffee...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is due to a mistake in your code.

```
for(j; j<8; j++)
{
    fscanf(in_file, "%lf", &AttPos[i]);
}
```

That array index should be j not i, your values aren't actually being put into the array.